# Inverse of function arcsin

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

I'm having trouble finding the solution of the inverse of the function
${\rm f}\left(y\right) = \arcsin\left(\,3 - x^2\,\right)$

Isn't $\arcsin$ the inverse of $\sin$ ?. This is what I have now as inverse:
$\sin\left(\,3 - x^2\,\right)$.

Comment: Do you mean $x^2$ with x2?

Comment: $y=\arcsin{3-x^2}\implies\sin(y)=3-x^2 \implies \sqrt{3-\sin(y)} = x$. I leave it to you to find out where the function is defined.

Comment: The definition of $f$ is wrong (or at least weird) since the argument $y$ does not appear in the right hand side. As it stands it is a constant function (where $x$ is some constant), and has no inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y(x)=\arcsin(3-x^2)\iff x(y)=\sqrt{3-\sin(y)}$$.